# TextToSpeech Locale_LANGUAGE in variable

Tags: locale, text-to-speech

im using the TextToSpeech() Object. The Object needs a setter for the language:

```
ttsobject.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

but i need it in this way:

```
ttsobejct.setLanguage(language);
```

Now I would set the language in another function in the same class. I created a global variable

```
private Locale language;
```

and initialize it in a function with

```
language = Locale.ENGLISH;
```

The problem is, that the language will not set. tts.speak() is muted. When I set the language in the constructer, it works:

```
ttsobject.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Do I inizialize the Locale variable wrong?